Counter example to the theorem that $X$ is hausdorff if and only if the diagonal of $X\times X$ is closed
If looking at $\mathbb R^n$ with the Zariski topology, the diagonal of $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is closed in the Zariski topology but the space $\mathbb R^n$ isn't Hausdorff with the Zariski topology.
Isn't this a contradiction to the theorem?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The Zariski topology on $\Bbb R^{2n}$ does not agree with the product topology on $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$, where each $\Bbb  R^n$ is equipped with the Zariski topology.

@AlessandroCodenotti Thanks! If so how can i show that the diagonal isn't close with respect to the product topology?

@daniel pick any two nonempty Zariski open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\Bbb R^n$, then there must be $x\in U\cap V$, which means that $(x,x)\in U\times V$, that is the complement of the diagonal does not contain the product of any two nontrivial open sets, hence it cannot be open, so that the diagonal cannot be closed

(Your observation in the question body is also a proof that the diagonal is not closed, if you've already proved the theorem that a space is Hausdorff iff the diagonal is closed in its square)

@AlessandroCodenotti Amazing thank you for the help!
